# why is it a bad idea to use arrays as the data structure in a bounded Queue?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, queue

I was thinking of implementing bounded Queues (of fixed capacity) using arrays. I then stumbled upon this [wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29#Example_C.2B.2B_language_code_using_array) on bounded-queues. It mentioned:

> An array is inefficient because of
>   time spent copying items to the front
>   of the queue

I didn't quite understand how is that true ? When we enqueue or dequeue, we are just updating the indices to head or tail. Where are we copying items to the front of the queue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no copying - the statement is incorrect. If you look back through the history of the article someone had code that actually did move all the items, but that code got replaced by the version you see now and the incorrect statement was left there. Also there is at least one error in the C++ code there. In the enqueue(), the condition `if(tail<head+QMAX)` will never fail since with the given code tail will never be greater than or equal to QMAX.

Comment: I felt so too. Glad to know I was on the right track. While we are at it, are there any disadvantages to using arrays for a bounded Queue. (assuming, I take care of under/overflow) ?

Comment: The only disadvantage to using an array is that you will be allocating space for the entire queue up front, even if only a fraction of it is being used. It is possible to only allocate a small array and then reallocate as it grows, but reallocation may require copying all of the existing elements to the newly allocated memory. Using a linked structure avoids this problem entirely, however it has disadvantages of its own such as more space overhead per node.

Comment: One reason to use point-in-time references ("permanent link" like https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Queue_(abstract_data_type)&oldid=985451470) to wiki articles. The code shown today still uses `push` and `shift`, operations that really move all elements. As the article does not mention ring buffers, I think it had quite poor quality.